# jQuery click() não está executando

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando fazer uma função em jQuery que ao clicar no *button* ele executada a função **click()** do jQuery para pegar os dados dos inputs e enviar via post.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="nome" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Nome" required="required" />
<input type="email" name="email"  class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Endereço de email" required="required" />
<input type="text" name="dominio" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Domínio" required="required" />
<button type="submit" class="btn submit" id="submit">Criar uma conta</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#submit").click(function()
        {
            var nome = $("input[name=nome]").val();
            var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
            var dominio = $("input[name=dominio]").val();
            $.post('api.php', {nome:nome, email:email}, function(data)
            {   
                alert(data);    
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

No console do browser aparece um erro:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Datex is not defined preco.php:29 (anonymous
>   function) preco.php:29 (anonymous function) preco.php:30 Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: _gaq is not defined global.js:1 (anonymous function)
>   global.js:1 o jquery.min.js:2 p.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
>   e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2 c.addEventListener.B

Comment: Ele não me retorna nada. Eu clico no botão e não acontece nada. Nem exibe o alert()

Comment: Tem um `<form>` em volta desses campos ou não? Se tiver, inclua o código na pergunta.

Comment: Não tem <form>.

Comment: O erro parece no php agora :(

Comment: Para esclarecer por que fechei esta pergunta: o autor comentou na resposta abaixo que havia um problema na ordem de carregamento dos arquivos js. Considerei improvável que outra pessoa tenha o mesmo problema com o mesmo sintoma (o erro acima).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenta esse código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(event){

        event.stopPropagation();

        var nome = $("input[name=nome]").val();
        var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
        var dominio = $("input[name=dominio]").val();

        $.post('api.php', {nome:nome, email:email}, function(data){

            alert(data);
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

O problema acontece pq seu `button` tem `type="submit"`. O browser entende que ao clicar neste botão o usuário estará submetendo uma informação ao servidor.

Usando o `event.stopPropagation()` vc garante que o evento não se propague.

O `return false` no fim da função é necessário para parar o processamento do evento ([leia isto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122375/jquery-event-stoppropagation-seems-not-to-work))

Comment: Continua não retornando nada. Apenas clico e não acontece nada, mesmo usando o type como button ou colocando **<input type="button">**

Comment: Editei o código. Tenta colocar `return false;` no fim da função callback.

Comment: Nada, continua não acontecendo nenhuma ação;

Comment: Eu acabei de ler o que vc editou na pergunta, parece que tem erro no seu código 'api.php' (server-side).
Vc pode debugar fazendo `console.log("algum texto");` para conferir até onde o código javascript (client-side) está indo. Sugiro colocar um log antes e depois da sua chamada `$.post`.

Comment: Consegui arrumar. Coloquei o código JS embaixo do jquery.js